# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs with AMD drivers so do I have to install 15.10 to get fglrx back?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-device-driver

SO I read the warning

"If you use the AMD Catalyst (fglrx) driver on Ubuntu you may wish to avoid upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS next month."

and figured that I wouldn't get hit with it so like a moron I installed 16.04!!

BUT I run Kodi streaming media to watch tv and it keeps locking up as I no longer have the old fglrx/catalyst driver which worked fine. It's too expensive to replace my card SO is the only option to reinstall and old version of Ubuntu OR is there a new driver out there I can install?? if so where is the web site please?

My card 
XFX AMD Radeon HD 5450 2GB DDR3 VGA/DVI/HDMI PCI-Express Video Card ON-XFX1-DLX2

the article with the explanation of the issue

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, that's the case.

This page may be of interest to you:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/3075837/linux/amds-gaming-optimized-amdgpu-pro-driver-for-linux-is-in-beta.html

Comment: Thanks for the link BUT my chip 5450 isn't supported I did read the article before and it had my hopes up :-(  I suppose I am going to have to reload 15.10 which means I lose my genesis app which I loved. Ho hum. thanks again

Comment: not complaining but why the down vote on my question? I did look into it pretty thoroughly and was just asking if I had missed something?

Comment: @theakson: I didn't downvote the question, but it's off-topic for this site, since it's not a programming question. Consider posting in [ubuntu.se].

Comment: WOW that's embarressing I didn't even find Ask Ubuntu. I deserve the downvote and to be sent to coventry for extreme stupidity and ignorance. Thanks for the point @KeithThompson you are a good man.

Comment: It happens all the time, and we deal with it. No need to beat yourself up.

Answer (score 0):

So before this gets closed, here's a similar question. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/794017/amd-drivers-ubuntu-16-04

The new beta driver is up https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx

i couldn't download a few days ago (that url gave 401 unauthorized) but now works, i'm installing this at this moment.

Comment: I just tried installing it, with a R7 200, it installs great, but then it boots with a no-signal monitor. i have no idea what's the problem. But i bet the problem is that it's not actually on the supported hardware list :(